# Where can I ask about gathering traffic data flows?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to find an answer about "How can I gather traffic flows of a certain application?"

I want to know how I can gather traffic of an application in different networks remotely.

Suppose that I am a client of an ISP and I can run a certain application (Skype) on my laptop and gather its traffic flows in a .pcap format by Microsoft Network Monitor for once (once the application connected through my laptop, an
automated program -Macro Recorder- started them, then closed the connection and Microsoft Network Monitor can see Skype and get its traffic flows in a .pcap file).

For accuracy in my traffic analysis, I can not just rely on this traffic that was gathered just by my laptop because it has statistical features that is particular to one ISP or network. I should gather traffic of this app by this method from more ISPs and networks. How can I do this remotely?

I should have access to other networks or ISP to run Skype through them and run the automated program and get the .pcap file of Skype. Is there any platform which can do this? Does **Planet-lab** do this?

Where and how can I reach to answer?

Comment: That seems awful broad, if that is your whole question.  Can you flesh it out here, and give us more info on what it is you're trying to do, and why you're going about it in this specific way?

Comment: I want to know how can gather traffic flows of a certain app. this question is in computer science and in traffic flows analysis and somehow is in data-mining and data analysis. Despite of that I asked it in stackoverflow and tagged it by "data-analysis","trafficshaping" and "network-traffic". But a person gave me a feedback that my question is not proper. I want to know why and where can asked it.

Comment: Yes, we understand that part.  But in order to help figure out if this can be asked anywhere, we need far more information about your actual question, so please edit additional details into your question.

Comment: "I want to know how can gather traffic flows of a certain app." <- What app? Which language? On which System? One time or durable gathering? For which purpose? All those questions would be needed to answer the question, and as such to tell on which site it could be on-topic.

Comment: I think if you have traffic analysis knowledge you should understand these questions. As I said certain app I meant that I want to gather traffic of a network-based app such as skype. there is no language....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on)

Comment: I think in the last edit which I did, I narrow the problem. Is there any vague  yet?

Comment: Would the information you seem to require not be company-confidential?  You should reach a commercial agreement with Skype/whatever to allow access to traffic-flow data.  Talk to a lawyer first, after all, what you seem to be trying to do may be seen to be immoral/illegal, (espionage even).

Comment: @M.Binsonek I've a pretty large knowledge of traffic analysis, capture, and in your first version I can't tell if you're willing to use netflows from your router or basic capture on the workstation, or if you should include analytics in your application. If you don't own the servers on the other side nor the whole routing system inbetween you won't get more than your workstation and using different link doesn't make much sense if what you're after is the application and not the link quality.

Answer (score 9):

Your question is far too broad to ask anywhere on the SE network.  You have a problem statement, but no approach to solving the problem.  You don't have a specific application you want to test, you don't have a language you want to use.  All you have is a vague, "This is my problem.  How do I solve it?"

Without even beginning to solve your own problem, there are literally thousands, if not millions, of ways to go about it.  You need to narrow your problem down to something someone can actually help with.  You do this by researching your issue, learning about how things work, what techniques you can use to capture information.  You choose a language and begin building your specific solution.  Once you have a more specific, narrow problem, then you have a problem that might be something we can help with, but where to ask will depend on where the problem lies.

Comment: You didn't answer to question. I think you don't have any knowledge about the traffic analysis, my question is lucid and understandable for an amateur internet traffic analyzer, also I narrow my question as you see but you didn't answer to it. So it is clear that your answer isn't more than a **pretext**.

Comment: No, I don't have any knowledge of traffic analysis.  But I have a good idea of how SE works, and what it accepts.  Your question is too broad because you haven't even started formulating the potential solution; you expect the readers to figure it out for you, which isn't what SE does, at all.

Comment: @fbueckert I do have some experience of traffic analysis, and since it's a well-known electronics-intelligence, (spying), tool, I would not recommend the OP's question to any site on SE.  If the OP wants to risk a long prison sentence or firing squad, fine, but s/he should not try and drag SE contributors into such activities.

Comment: @M.Binsonek I don't see anything remotely funny.  Also, your abuse/profanity came out as dots...

Comment: @Martin James thank you for your research. That was not an abuse, it was just a fun.